# iAd width in landscape on iPad is narrow

Tags: ios, iad

I have an iAd in an iPad app. When the user rotates, I use setFrame to tell the ad's view to resize and move to the bottom of the screen. Unfortunately, although I am setting the width to 1024, iOS is not complying and the iAd's switch is remaining at 768.

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately setting that value in my rotate routine causes the program to crash.

Answer (score 1):

To resize the banner view you must use the `currentContentSizeIdentifier` property.  The documentation:

> Your application should never directly change the size of the banner view. Instead, set the currentContentSizeIdentifier property to a known advertising size. The view is automatically resized to match the new content size.

So to resize the banner view for landscape, you would do the following:

`bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;`

If you need to know the actual size this will change the banner view's frame to, use the ADBannerView class method `sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:`.  So if you resize the banner view for landscape, then the new size will be

```
CGSize bannerViewSize = [ADBannerView sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
```